# How to use @for loop in laravel controller

Tags: laravel

Currently I have this code in my blade file

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($orderProduct->column['Position']); $i++)
      <p>{{ $orderProduct->column['Position'][$i] }}</p>
      <p>{{ $orderProduct->column['Color'][$i] }}</p>
@endfor
```

How do I use the @for loop in controller so that it outputs the same result?

I tried something like this

```
foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($orderProduct->column['Position']); $i++) {

$message .= "<p>" . $orderProduct->column['Position'][$i] . " : " . $orderProduct->column['Color'][$i] . "</p>";

}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: what you get if dd($orderProduct)

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve a JSON array from DB column.

$orderProduct = {"Position":["first","second","third","fourth"],"Color":["Red",Blue,Pink,Teal]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` is for looping through arrays and other iterable objects, so it doesn't work with the same parameters as a `for` loop.

Simply change `foreach` to `for`.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($orderProduct->column['Position']); $i++) {

    $message .= "<p>" . $orderProduct->column['Position'][$i] . " : " . $orderProduct->column['Color'][$i] . "</p>";

}
```

Comment: But you are not showing him with blade, it is a normal PHP loop.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Correct. He asked how to "use `@for` loop in *controller*", not blade.

Answer (score 0):

Firest you have error in your json data

```
 $orderProduct = {"Position":["first","second","third","fourth"],"Color":["Red",Blue,Pink,Teal]}
```

`Blue,Pink,Teal`  doenst contain single quote or double quote.

So it should be

```
  $orderProduct = '{"Position":["first","second","third","fourth"],"Color":["Red","Blue","Pink","Teal"]}';
```

then you can use foreach like below

```
 $orderProduct = '{"Position":["first","second","third","fourth"],"Color":["Red","Blue","Pink","Teal"]}';
    $data=json_decode($orderProduct);
    foreach ($data as $key=>$value){

        echo  "<h4>".$key."</h4>";
        echo  implode("<br>",$value);

    }
```

This will ouput like below

**Position**

first
second
third
fourth

**Color**

Red
Blue
Pink
Teal

Also you can avoid implode if you want

```
 foreach ($data as $key=>$value){

        echo  "<h4>".$key."</h4>";
       foreach ($value as $subkey=>$subvalue){

           echo $subvalue."<br>";
       }

    }
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not defining the Json data with a variable.  I'm retrieving from Database so there's no issues with the array data. 
I was just showing what my array looks like. 

Secondly, I'm trying to output it something like this: 

first : Red

second : Blue

third : Pink


Any ideas?

Comment: loop will be same no issues.if you still get errror let me know.i have tested it